# Why is for (1; 2; 3) an infinite loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

In a program to print `hello`:

```
for (1; 2; 3) 
printf ("Hello");
```

Why does the output show its an infinite loop? Isn't `for ( ; ; )` alone an infinite loop?

Comment: Because any number that is different than zero is considered `true` for boolean operations. So, the second operand in the for loop is then not the number `2` but an always `true` boolean statement.

Comment: @user5268195 > No you won't or you won't stay long here. Maintaining SO's quality is every community member's business.

Comment: While this might not be a good or interesting question, it is a valid question as far as SO policies are concerned. Being rude is however not ok.

Comment: This is a bit unacceptable. I'm not sure what the argument is about here - this seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me? The answer might be obvious to those who are more experience with C / C++ programming, but that's no reason for the hostility towards the OP.

Comment: Also, why close vote for "too broad"? This question is about as narrow as they get.

Comment: @Lundin Hi thanks, I'm new to this app and I'm still figuring out how it works. Bear with me

Comment: @user3728501 Thank you. I'm a beginner learning C programming and i dont have much guidance except this app

Comment: @user5268195 FYI, this is a Q/A site, not an app.

Comment: @user5268195 In that case I'd suggest getting a book. [This list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) has a good number of recommendations.

Comment: @nemetroid Sure, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Hmm you correct. In `C` for structure is

```
for ( initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
```

So, In your code, `for (1; 2; 3)` here in condition part (ie. middle) is a `non-zero (ie. 2)` and it,s always true. That's why your code always get `true` condition and `infinite loop` occur.

According to [infinite Loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm) Definition in `For Loop`:

> When the conditional expression is absent, it is assumed to be true.
>   You may have an initialization and increment expression, but C
>   programmers more commonly use the for( ; ; ) construct to signify an
>   infinite loop.

For better Understanding, you can follow [For Looop](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html)

Comment: @user5268195  If you like this, your should accept this answer. It also help for you.

Answer (score 3):

In C, all non-zero integers are considered as true. So here,

```
for (1; 2; 3)
```

2 is a non-zero integer and so, it is an infinite loop. And yes,

```
for ( ; ; )
```

is also an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

`for` will halt once the second statement evaluates to 0. (An empty statement counts as non-zero in this context).

Yours never does. `for(1; 2; 3)`, `for(; 2;)`, and `for(;;)` will not halt.